# Capturing traffic of GATWAY<>LAN in router using iptables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I'm trying to capture traffic of LAN<>GATEWAY of a router. The router has linux based firmware and I can use iptables for doing network stuff. What I want to do is capture the traffic in gray area in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rid3t.png) picture. I will use netfilter-queue to capture redirected traffic.

Traffic what I capture has to be..

1. After DNAT on inbound traffic(WAN->LAN).
2. Before SNAT on outbound traffic(WAN<-LAN).

I found some picture explaining about iptables chains [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF1uo.jpg). I figured out some scenarios for capture such things. But every picture is based on single system so I'm not sure it will work well. It would be different but let's just think eth0 is connected with WAN and eth1 is connected with LAN.

1. Capture traffics in FORWARED chain of filter or mangle table.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -j NFQUEUE
```

2. Capture traffics in PREROUTING chain of mangle table.

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -j NFQUEUE
```

3. Capture traffics in PREROUTING chain of eth1(LAN) and POSTROUTING chain of eth0(WAN).

```
iptables -t mangle -i eth1 -I PREROUTING -j NFQUEUE
iptables -t mangle -i eth0 -I POSTROUTING -j NFQUEUE
```

What would be the best choice to capture LAN<>GATEWAY traffic? It would be best if I can try all of them but I don't have access to router so I can't test now.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this today and I'm going to share it now. I was able to capture packets after DNAT and before SNAT using FORWARD chain. So the answer was 1.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -j NFQUEUE
```

Now I'm trying to find the way to capture packets for specific host(using host's MAC address).